# Level curves of function $f(x,y) = |x| + y$?

Tags: calculus

How can I find the level curves of the function $(,)= |x| + y$?

I started with $(,)=$ ($$ being a real number). But i don't have a clue how to continue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider cases where $x\ge0$ and $x<0$ separately

Comment: Would you be able to process $f(x,y)=x+y$ ?

Comment: The level curve of $f(x,y)$ are the curves defined by $z=0,\,f(x,y)=c,$ where $c$ is a real number, whenever they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=k \implies y=k-|x|$$

For different values of $k$ you get level curves parallel to the graph of $y=-|x|$.